# Impossible to Mock RestTemplate constructor

Tags: java, spring, mockito, resttemplate

I have write default interface method and i want to test that but i have a junit error "Application context fail".

My test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SecurityCodeRepository.class})
public class SecurityCodeRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired
    private SecurityCodeRepository repo;

    @Spy
    private CustomClientHttpRequestFactory factory;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testRepoWhenResponse() {
        // INIT
        final SecurityCodeIn wo = new SecurityCodeIn("123458");
        final ResponseEntity<SecurityCodeOut> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(new SecurityCodeOut(true, false), HttpStatus.OK);
        when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(),
                any(HttpMethod.class),
                any(HttpEntity.class), any(Class.class), anyString())).thenReturn(responseEntity);

        // PROCESS
        final SecurityCodeOut out = repo.callWS(wo, "urlWs", HttpMethod.POST, new SecurityCheckErrorHandler(), SecurityCodeOut.class,
                "ff32223b-bde5-4d60-a21d-4e3e01dcd416");

        // CHECKS
        assertTrue(out.isRetry());
        assertFalse(out.isStatus());
    }

}
```

My repository to test :

```
    @Repository
public class SecurityCodeRepository implements GenericRepository<SecurityCodeIn, SecurityCodeOut> {

    /**
     * Error LOGGER.
     */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityCodeRepository.class);

    /** The x caller key. */
    @Value("${service.x-caller-key}")
    private String xCallerKey;

    /** The Constant APP_CALLER_KEY. */
    private static final String APP_CALLER_KEY = "App-caller-key";

    @Autowired
    private CustomClientHttpRequestFactory factory;

    @Override
    public HttpHeaders getHeader() {
        final HttpHeaders headersCompleted = new HttpHeaders();
        headersCompleted.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headersCompleted.set(APP_CALLER_KEY, xCallerKey);

        return headersCompleted;
    }

    @Override
    public Logger getLogger() {
        return LOGGER;
    }

    @Override
    public CustomClientHttpRequestFactory getFactory() {
        return this.factory;
    }
}
```

My Interface :

```
public interface GenericRepository<I extends Object, O extends Object> {
    HttpHeaders getHeader();

    Logger getLogger();

    CustomClientHttpRequestFactory getFactory();

    default O callWS(final I elementIn, final String url, final HttpMethod method, final ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler, final Class<O> classe,
            final Object... paramsUrl) {
        final HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(elementIn, getHeader());
        ResponseEntity<O> responseEntity = null;

        // Create new restTemplate

        final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getFactory().init(false));
        // add logger for debug
        restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor()));

        // add process error
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(errorHandler);

        try {
            getLogger().info("Appel du webService - {} - {}", url, method);
            responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, httpEntity,
                    classe, paramsUrl);
        } catch (final RestClientResponseException rce) {
            getLogger().error("RestClientException - {}", url, rce);
        }

        // If there is no response, throw technical exception
        if (responseEntity == null) {
            throw new WebServiceException("Impossible de contacter l'API ".concat(url));
        }

        return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
}
```

My test call my repository who implements interface and uses default method. So, This test must mock getFactory(). Actually, this object is null in junit test. :/

How can i test my GenericRepository mocking my RestTemplate ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

With the `@SpringBootTest` annotation, Spring Boot provides a convenient way to start up an application context to be used in a test. And by using `classes` we can tell Spring Boot which application class to use to create an application context.
But you for some reason have pointed out the `SecurityCodeRepository.class` as a `classes` parameter. You should replace it with `Application.class` or remove at all.
[Here](https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-test/) you can find out a full explanation